How to set Proxy from the Kameleo API?
What would be the proper code syntaxes forms to set the Proxy details/credentials from the Kameleo API?
Also, could your provide some example codes?

Below are examples of how to set up a proxy using the Local API Clients in different programming languages:
For Javascript:
const createProfileRequest = BuilderForCreateProfile
  .forBaseProfile(chromeBaseProfileList[0].id)
  .setRecommendedDefaults()
  .setProxy(
    'socks5', # Options ('http', 'socks5', 'ssh')
    {
      host: '<proxy_host>',
      port: <proxy_port>,
      id: '<username>',
      secret: '<password>',
    },
  )
  .build();
const profile = await client.createProfile({ body: createProfileRequest });

For Python:
create_profile_request = BuilderForCreateProfile \
  .for_base_profile(base_profiles[0].id) \
  .set_recommended_defaults() \
  .set_proxy('socks5', Server(host='<proxy_host>', port=<proxy_port>, id='<username>', secret='<password>')) \
  .build()
profile = client.create_profile(body=create_profile_request)

For C#:
var createProfileRequest = BuilderForCreateProfile
  .ForBaseProfile(baseProfileList[0].Id)
  .SetRecommendedDefaults()
  .SetProxy("socks5", new Server("<proxy_host>", <proxy_port>, "<username>", "<password>"))
  .Build();

var profile = await client.CreateProfileAsync(createProfileRequest);

These answers are provided from the Kameleo Set Proxy from API article.
